# Weird bug in Yii when cookie expires

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I have a problem when the cookie expires in Yii. Everything seems to work fine with other tables. When the cookie expires the user is redirected in the login page. But I have a problem in a particular model. In this model when the cookie expires not only it doesn't logout the user, it also returns wrong results. I though that maybe there is something wrong in my model search() method. But I can't figure out what. Everything pretty seems normal. Here is the code:

```
public function search()
{
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('contractid',$this->contractid);
        $criteria->compare('t.schoolclassid',$this->schoolclassid);
        $criteria->compare('schoolclass.schoolid',$this->schoolid);
        $criteria->compare('schoolclass.gradeid',$this->gradeid);
        $criteria->compare('t.studentid',$this->studentid);
        $criteria->compare('regno',$this->regno);
        $criteria->compare('contractdate',$this->contractdate,true);
        $criteria->compare('startdate',$this->startdate,true);
        $criteria->compare('pausedate',$this->pausedate,true);
        $criteria->compare('enddate',$this->enddate,true);
        $criteria->compare('totalcost',$this->totalcost,true);
        $criteria->compare('totalxcost',$this->totalxcost,true);
        $criteria->compare('closed',$this->closed);
        //For Filtering with Student
        $criteria->with = array('student','schoolclass.school');
        if (Yii::app()->user->CompanyID) {
           $criteria->compare('school.companyid',Yii::app()->user->CompanyID);
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->SchoolID) {
            $criteria->compare('schoolclass.schoolid',Yii::app()->user->SchoolID);
        }
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('student.lastname', $this->studentLastname);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('student.firstname', $this->studentFirstname);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'student.lastname ASC',
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>50,               
            ),
        ));          
}
```

Can someone explain what causes this issue? Or suggest a workaround?

Comment: are you using `srbac`?

Comment: I don't know what `srbac` is...

Comment: I just googled it. No I don't use `srbac`

Comment: check `accessRules` in your controller, maybe this action is allowed even for non-logged in user ?

Comment: Thank you very much Criesto. Some access rules were missing and I hadn't notice. This seems to fix the problem.